# Set label text from one view to anther

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to let the user go into his/her settings where they would set a name.  Once they click save the name would then be put on the main screen label without the need to relaunch the application. How can I do this, the easiest way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a settings view controller, I assume you have some sort of model object to keep track of saved settings. In that model object you should keep track of the user name.

In your main view controller just add:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    self.userNameLabel.text = [self.modelObject valueForKey:@"userName"];
}
```